# App Launcher in Blackberry 10

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have an application which opens on the Url Link on the Browser.this works fine on Android .
the code i gave in AndroidManifest is ::

```
 android:exported="true"
                <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="app" />
```

But this is not working on Blackberry 10 simulator & playbook phone.

Can anybody please help !
Thanks in advance...

Comment: i have no programming experience on BB10 , but i think that since it's a totally different OS and framework, it's very possible that some android features are not available on it. maybe this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in BB10, as any system-wide services:

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html

Comment: It's in fact possible on Cascades apps, as explained in this entry: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/07/invoke-my-app/#more-15652 . So maybe there is a way in Android